# Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm still a newb when it comes to using regular expressions. I am trying to set up a regular expression where "0" will never match if it is by itself. I have 5 test expressions. The last 4 should match and the first one shouldn't. However I can seem to only get the middle3 to match. How can i set it to get the last one to match as well?

```
<?php
$data1='0';
$data2='New Triggered By Test 01';
$data3='Hello';
$data4='01 Test';
$data5='00';

$pattern='/[^0]{1}/';

echo preg_match($pattern,$data1);

echo preg_match($pattern,$data2);

echo preg_match($pattern,$data3);

echo preg_match($pattern,$data4);

echo preg_match($pattern,$data5)
?>
```

Comment: Your expressions says that you should have 1 or more characters that are not "0".
"00" have no any characters that are not "0". Please show another strings that should not match, as with the current case you even do not need a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to match is

- A single char that's not `0`
- Or more than one char

Try this one:

```
"#^([^0]|.{2,})$#"
```

Commented:

```
"/^      # begining of the input string
(
  [^0]   # one char, everything but zero
  |.{2,} # or any sequence of more than one char
)$/"
```

---

Test script:

```
$inputs = array(
    '0',
    'New Triggered By Test 01',
    'Hello',
    '01 Test',
    '00',
);

foreach($inputs as $input) {
    echo "$input: ";

    if (preg_match("#^([^0]|.{2,})$#", $input)) {
        echo "OK\n";
    } else {
        echo "NOT OK\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you deducted that set of rules from the OP's question. This doesn't match his cases 2 and 3.

Comment: @Tuga, yes, it works. @Juhana, he wants to match everything except a string that's only a `0`.

Comment: Right, my point was that in the original answer the second condition was a subset of the first one... It's enough to just check that the string doesn't match `'0'`.

Comment: RegexBuddy is giving false negatives... after running it in php I've realized it was working, sorry about that, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep it simple:

```
$data !== '0';
```

Comment: Solves the underlying problem in this case, but the author really specifically asked for a regular expression.

Comment: !==, otherwise that'd trigger on `''` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be a RegularExpression or else I would do this

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern='/^(0.+|[^0]).*$/';
```

Either a zero, followed by atleast one other character, or a string that doesn't start with zero.

Live proof of concept on IDEONE: http://ideone.com/2RXrr